# Solution to Verhulst Model

Tags: integration, differential, substitution

I'm currently trying to solve the differential equation
$$\frac{dN}{dt} = rN\bigg(1-\big(\frac{N}{k}\big)^2\bigg)$$
Where N is the population of a fish and r, k are positive constants.

I've tried rearranging and using the substitution $u = N^{-2}$ but i'm not having much luck due to the two separate terms on the RHS. ie.

Using the substitution, $du = -\frac{dN}{N}$ and $u = N^{-2}$.

$$\int -u \cdot du =  \int (ru - \frac{r}{k^2})\cdot dt$$

Is the furthest I can make it!

Comment: \begin{align}
N' &= rN \left( 1 - N^{2}/k^{2} \right) \\
\implies k^{2} N' &= rN \left( k^{2} - N^{2} \right) \\
&= rN (k+N)(k-N) \\
\implies dt &= \frac{k^{2}}{r} \cdot \frac{dN}{N (k+N)(k-N)}
\end{align}

Now use partial fractions on the RHS.

Comment: Indeed, the change of variable $$u=N^2/k^2$$ yields $$u'=2ru(1-u)$$ hence $$\frac{u'}{u(1-u)}=2r=\frac{u'}u+\frac{u'}{1-u}$$ which implies $$\log\left|\frac{u}{1-u}\right|=2rt+c$$ that is, $$\frac{u}{1-u}=ce^{2rt}$$ or $$u=\frac{ce^{2rt}}{1+ce^{2rt}}$$ that is, $$N(t)=\frac{ke^{rt}}{\sqrt{e^{rt}+c}}$$ where the value of $c$ may change from line to line.

Comment: @Did [+1] One can add that your transformed differential equation $u'=2ru(1-u)$ is the classical logistic differential equation (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LogisticEquation.html).

Comment: *Typo: Replace $e^{rt}$ by $e^{2rt}$ in the square root in the denominator of $N(t)$.